# Show Next/Previous from table record using JQuery

Tags: php, mysql

On Page load I read 10 random records from mysql table using PHP. Now I want to display each record using Next/Previous button using JQUERY on the same page. What is the best way to do so?
Its not pagination because I have to show same 10 records I read at the time of page load.

Comment: Use jPaginate http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/11/17/jpaginate-a-fancy-jquery-pagination-plugin/ ( A jquery plugin )

Comment: Its not pagination because I have to show same 10 records I read at the time of page load.

Comment: I dont think it can be "Next" or "Previous" since you query 10 random records. Maybe you can try something like "Show more" so you can re-query 10 random records into same place.

Answer (score 0):

hey i know it's not pagination but check out this link...this might solve your problem...http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php_paging2.php